# Different DataTemplate for each item in a RadListView

Tags: uwp, telerik

I have a RadListView where the ItemsSource is bound to a list of document types, and there are multiple document types in this list (like Word, Excel, ++)

Now I want to use a different datatemplate for each document type, so I have this code:

```
<Data:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DocumentTemplateSelector}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</Data:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
```

But this results in the template for the first document type used for the entire list. Like the template for Word also used for Excel. Is this a bug or are there other ways to have different DataTemplates for different types?

For a normal ListView, the following works just fine (correct template is used for each type):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DocumentTemplateSelector}" >
```

For a RadListView, specifying a ItemTemplateSelector does not work in the same way, the template for the first document is still used for the entire list.

Comment: <DataTemplate  x:DataType="yourdocumentmodel"   >

Comment: How did you make your `DocumentTemplateSelector`? I want to check your code. Please provide a [mcve].